# Why is angularjs ngShow sample not working on their site?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

My page has several animations, all working well.
However one div based on ngShow refuses to accept my animation, while it works on `ngRepeat`, `ngView`, `ngSwitch`, etc.

I checked the docs for [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and their own example does not work on their site. I noticed it works on Plunker but what causes it to fail on the docs page?

Edit: For completeness: Here is a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4npH7Hy5uJpa0B3iRUJY?p=preview) that only work partially. The first one does not trigger the foo.enter animation, the second one does.
Edit2: I updated the Plnkr to use ng 1.3.x

Comment: It's working for me with Angular v1.3.17 (stable release) but not on v1.4.4-build.4160. My suggestion is to use a stable version of angular for anything serious.

Comment: Congratulations! you may have found a bug, either with documentation or with the library/framework itself. The issue tracker is likely a much better place to post about this.

Comment: This works for me using  angular 1.4.3 in chrome as an fyi

Comment: @yvesmancera Changed Plnkr to 1.3.x, doesn't work. The check box does not initiate an animation.

Comment: @DougEFresh Tested with Chrome on Win 10, no, my Plnkr does not work, ngShow does neither, no animation shown.

Comment: Do you see the animations here http://plnkr.co/edit/4LjCTiMDX3Ro7lAog4jc?p=preview

Comment: @DougEFresh, yes. I forgot to mention that their sample works in Plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

Animations are really hard to unit test,  my guess is that there isn't a unit test covering this specific functionality and since it is a snapshot build branch and not a version branch so it most likely took them awhile to catch this.  It seems like they have an open issue for this problem.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12267

Comment: I wonder where the difference to my code is, as this is on 1.3.x and not working.

Comment: There are a number of ways to show/hide elements in angular and I was able to verify in chrome from the https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/docs/api/ng/directive/ngShow website that this is working at least from my perspective from this specific version, I am not saying there are not other issues going on there are some 50 open issues for ng-animate right now and it is hard to narrow down each specific one related to this issue.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+ng-animate